# Determine which arraylist is currently being used?

Tags: java, listview, arraylist, javafx, switch-statement

I have a listview being populated by an arraylist, and a combobox that, when items are selected, clear the listview and populate it with a different arraylist. This works fine, but the issue is, I've got it set up so that when an item is selected in the listview, it displays information on the item based on the item's index in the arraylist. When switching arraylists, the information displayed is obviously still using the index of the original arraylist. Is there any way I can check to see which list is being used to stop this?

The listener on the listview:

```
String item = lv_left.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();    //if clicked once, sets selected to appear
                lv_left.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val){
                        tooltip.setText(new_val);
                        int index = lv_left.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
//Here would be my switch statement for the array index
```

I'm originally populating the listview like this:

```
ListView<String> lv_left = new ListView<>
    (FXCollections.observableArrayList(cleric_cantrips));
```

And here is when I switch listviews:

```
levels.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val){
            String value = levels.getValue();

            switch (value){
            case "Caster Level": lv_left.getItems().clear(); lv_left.getItems().addAll(cleric_cantrips);                 
            break;
            case "Level 1": lv_left.getItems().clear(); lv_left.getItems().addAll(cleric_lvl_1);        
            break;
//etc.
```

Is this viable? Since I'm changing the items in the list with `lv_left.getItems().addAll(cleric_lvl_1);`, is there a way that I can make an `if` statement or something up where I've got the switch statement for the index, so that if it's `cleric_cantrips` then use that arraylist for the index? Or would I have to do this manually and use a switch based on the string of the item? Either would work, but I feel that it'd be a bit cleaner and a bit shorter to use indexes rather than having to type out each item in the switch.

Comment: Actually, seeing as how I have things set up, it would be easier and more efficient to have it in a large switch statement filtered by the string rather than index, so that's what I'll do. That being said, I'll leave this question here, as I would still like to know if what I've asked is possible for future use, as well as anyone else who may have this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

- `if(lv_left.getItems().containsAll(cleric_cantrips)))`
- `if(levels.getValue().equals("Caster level"))`
- Or you could just add your own boolean variable to keep track which list is being used.